# Please enable cross site notifications

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications

I noticed when I was using SO and meta today that I was hoping back and forth between the two to see if I had any notifications on the other.  It would be cool/nice to see notifications pop-ups for other sites that you are registered under the same Open-ID.  The same could be said about the letter icon to the left of your name.  Maybe you could have multiple for each site your registered to, or turn red if something happens somewhere else as well.

Just some more food for thought.  Anyone else have any ideas for something like this?

Comment: +1 for this feature. Microsummary works, but it would be nice to have a "zero click" implementation for this feature.

Comment: +1: This will increase my responsive dramatically across sites. I often forget I have a question pending on another site.

Comment: I think need for this will increase with the addition of stackoverflow sites.  There are going to be some that you visit regularly but others that you only dip in and out of.  You shouldn't have to click through all of them just to check for updates.

Comment: +1 was just going to ask this myself.  I was ok with just the main 3, but with the addition of those area51 sites its going to be too much to switch between them.

Comment: We need this, mostly now with all the new sites coming...

Comment: [status-completed] with the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as how each of the sites (including Meta?) is it's own separate instance on it's own separate database, I don't know how well this would be implemented. I agree with the idea of being able to have one central location for your question and answers and recent activity, but I don't know how well cross-site notifications would be achieved.

Comment: While we are making user suggestions, we shouldn't consider the underlying architecture.  I agree this is hard, since we are (mostly) all developers, but if design is driven by architecture, and not by users, you end up with a site that is difficult to use and easy to develop.

Answer (score 2):

You could also have one question page that accessed all the SO sites, with the questions all in their own color.

Comment: Yeah, I think we need a meta-meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

Install [this microsummary](http://sam.haslers.info/firefox-microsummaries.html) and then bookmark each of your recent activity pages in Firefox's bookmarks toolbar.

Comment: What about Meta SO?

Comment: that microsummary works on meta too. I updated the title but forgot to update the description on the page.

Comment: broken link now

Comment: @forget it, hiccup with my hosting provider I think. It's back up now.