# Network-wide recent activity list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, recent-activity

It would be cool if the recent activity page (or maybe a new page with similar functionality) showed activity for your account on all sites in the SO family.

This would be useful for those of us that are in the crossover area between communities, so we can easily see how our stuff changed in the last day.

**EDIT:**
Its interesting how everyone jumped on this being a dupe (which I guess it is; I'm not disputing that) but nothing relevant came up in the possible dupe list when I was posting it.

Comment: Mega dupe, but I'm going with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3973/please-enable-cross-site-notifications

Comment: Just draw one out of a hat. Eventually you can follow the links back to the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now possible at http://stackexchange.com -- simply click the **network profile** link on your user profile page:

[image]

Here's your network-wide activity

https://stackexchange.com/users/3006?tab=activity