# Combine recent activity and user pages of SO/SF/SU/META

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, profile-page

Since I'm a user on all 4 sites, when I want to check for responses I have to individually visit each Recent Activity page. Can I have a "combined view" that aggregates data from all 4 sites on one page?

Also when checking up on a particular user, I'd like to see all his best questions and answers, not just those that relate to the *current* site.

Comment: Been suggested 50 times...

Comment: I don't see where.

Comment: It's a Dupe Overflow.

Comment: Here's one dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/network-wide-recent-activity-list

Comment: Its a good idea that almost everybody would benefit from.

Comment: And here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3973/please-enable-cross-site-notifications here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13708/please-make-a-recent-activity-page-that-shows-all-four-sites-activity here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/single-location-for-so-sf-su-user-info/ here: -error Dupe Overflow exception triggered-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sites are mutually exclusive. I don't think SO should implement anything like this. Most programmers on SO won't care much for the activity taking place on SU.

Comment: I humbly disagree. If I have accounts in both places, why wouldn't I be interested in updates from both places? It would make sense to provide a single dashboard for all related sites.

Answer (score 4):

You can now view all of your comments, reputation points, etc. on **every Stack Exchange site** in one place:

[StackCenter](http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com)

**There's even a global reputation graph!**

[image]

*If you like StackCenter, please vote for it [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange).*

Comment: Shameless plug to an awesome app!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have been realized with the network ('global') profile and the 'Top Network Posts' widget on the bottom left of each profile page, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131515/robinicks:

[image]

There's a link at the bottom which leads to the network profile, which gives a longer overview of the top questions and answers. The top posts of the author of the question are here: https://stackexchange.com/users/18060/jarvis

[image]

(for your own ones, visit https://stackexchange.com/users/current)

Checking for responses is best done via the global inbox, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/295232) is a list of notifications which end up there. Your own global inbox can be visited via the button in the top bar, all notifications will be collected on this page: https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox.